# Reading html with php file and execute php code inside the file

Tags: php, html, parsing

Can somebody tell me to run php inside an html file that is opened inside an php file.

Its like this.

I have an HTML file like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Some heading</h1>
        <? $sometekst_variable ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

What i whant is to open the file inside my php function and to let the function run the php inside the file. The php variable will be set inside the function where the file is read.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I doubt you'd want to do this. Possible sollutions involve `eval`.

Comment: Hmm, you want to parse the source? If not, I don't really understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). In your top file, do something like

```
include('otherfile.php');
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP. It stated he wanted to "to open the file inside my php function and to let the function run the php inside the file", which would require eval().

Comment: Including a file will execute the PHP in that file.

Comment: @jprofitt: You are correct. Sometimes I get caught up in questions that deviate from my coding practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via require 'that_template_file';
If you want to catch the html output of that file (e.g. run it, but not print it to the output stream), you can (must) use output buffers, like so:

```
<?php

function render($tpl) {
   // this way it would print out everything to the output, without a chance to grab that
   require $tpl; 
   // OR do it like this:
   ob_start();
   require $tpl;
   $parsed_result = ob_get_contents();
   // now you can print out the result or do something else with it...
   echo $parsed_result;
   // or return it
   return $parsed_result;
}

render('template.ext.php'); // note, it doesn't have to be .php... it can be anything
```

Also note that you can nest calls to ob_start, so you can nest the render function.

Like so:

index.php:
`<?php render('template.inc.php'); ?>`

template.inc.php:
`<div><?php render('header.inc.php'); ?></div>`

and so on.

Comment: Any point of downvoting valid anwer even with examples? And they told me I'm the upset one... lol.

Comment: Not sure why this got down-voted either... Maybe it is overkill?